# Is it possible to declare a variable in one javascript file and use it in another one?

Tags: javascript

If I had one javascript **file**:

```
var myVariable = "Awesome variable";
```

and another javascript **file**:

```
function printMyVariable() {
    document.writeln(myVariable);
}
```

would the `printMyVariable` method be able to recognize myVariable? My guess in "No", because the `myVariable` scope isn't recognizable in the second javascript file. So, I was wondering if someone could explain to me what needs to be done to make the magic happen, if possible. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as the file with the variable declaration is included before the file that uses it since it's all parsed in the same chunk but in order.

This is an exceptionally bad practice though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I completely agree that it is a horrific practice. Just one more question: If I declared a new variable in the second javascript file and gave it the same name it would "override" the previous one, right?

Comment: Yes as long as the second file in included after the first file.

Comment: re: exceptionally bad practice -- not really, because it is essentially the same as closure in local scope. Yes, it is closure too!

Comment: @user205376: I'm not indicating that as the bad practice. I'm indicating that having one file dependent on a variable in a separate file is a bad practice for code organization reasons and for execution safety. If the first file fails to download properly, then the second will experience errors as a result. Closure in local scope doesn't suffer the dependence on availability that separate files does.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible since myVariable will be defined @ global scope though its in a different file. However make sure printMyVariable function is called after the variable is defined (in terms of including the script tags.)

Answer (score 1):

### simple

JS has flat scope, there are global<sup>1</sup> and local only. `var` uses current scope. Let `var foo` be in global scope -- you will get global variable assessible from any of files (there are no namespaces or modules).

### further

There is a `Global` object, and the global var becomes a property of it. In the browser environment `window` implements `Global`, so your global var will have qualified name as `window.foo`.

### "redeclaring"

```
/* 
assuming browser environment
execution flow: top to bottom 
first file: (actually doesnt matter, becase its flat)
*/
var foo = "bar";
// equivalent to 
window.foo = "bar";

// second file:
var foo = 42;
// redeclared? no, because equivalent statement is
window.foo = 42;
```

<sup>1</sup> illustrative purpose only, see the second part.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you call the function in the second file after you include the first file, you should be fine. You introduce a global variable, which is assigned to the `window` object in the DOM, so after you include the first file, `window.myVariable` will be equal to `"Awesome variable"`. As mentioned above, though, all of this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As an old perlie, I would never use a variable starting with 'my' as a global variable - my = local in perl :-) I agree it's bad practice.

The way to think of this is not as seperate files, but as one big file of al the JavaScript files concatenated in order. The scope is the same as it would be in that file. Indeed, this is exactly what happens when you minify...